# How to create a custom text input filter?

Tags: 7, navigation, input-formats

I am using plain text format. I want to create an input filter for when a user enters #15, it should be converted to a link pointing to the post [#15](https://www.example.com/statuses/15). I want to do this for the [Statuses (Social Microblog)](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses) module. The link of an individual status is like this: `https://www.example.com/statuses/15`.

Just for your reference, I found a [snippet](https://www.drupal.org/node/210555#comment-2684916). It is specifically for nodes though, which was meant to be used with [custom filter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/customfilter).

**My question**: How to create such filter for [statuses](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses)?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Custom Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/customfilter) module.

> This module allows you to create content filter using regular expressions. Instead of creating a new module for each filter you need, now you can easily create and organize your own filters. Your filter will appear in the input format configuration page.

If you want to do it yourself in a custom module, you can implement [`hook_filter_info`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info/7.x)

Comment: I know about the module, but the question is, how to do it? I do not know what code to use.

Comment: Read the module's documentation: https://www.drupal.org/node/210551

Comment: I have read it 2 times before, but do not understand

Comment: Then you should open a support request on the module's issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/customfilter or you ask another explicit question on **what** you cannot understand.

Comment: What would you suggest after seeing this https://www.drupal.org/node/210555#comment-2684916

Answer (score 0):

The Linkit module almost does what you want:

https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit

handbook:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2647538

The user starts typing the title and gets the link. No need to remember any number or internal path structure.

Comment: Its description says that it is for entities. My question is about statuses, which is not an entity

Answer (score 0):

The Examples module has code for how to implement your own drupal "filters" (in your own module).

https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/filter_example%21filter_example.module/group/filter_example/7.x-1.x

Use them in a custom "text format" for your statuses.